# Octave - Split string into characters

Tags: matlab, octave

Using octave I want to split a string into its individual characters.

How do I do this?

For example converting

```
x = "hello"
```

to

```
c = [h, e, l, l, o]
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: In Octave array of characters is exactly the same thing as a string, so `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]` is simply a string `"hello"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already split in Matlab's string actually:

```
x = 'hello'
x(1)
>> h
```